# Is any language that can express its own compiler Turing-complete?

Tags: computability, turing-completeness

[A comment over on tex.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128454/are-there-any-open-research-problems-in-the-world-of-tex/153131?noredirect=1#comment289410_128464) made me wonder. The statement is essentially:

> If I can write a compiler for language X in language X, then X is Turing-complete.

In computability and formal languages terms, this is:

> If $M$ decides $L \subseteq L_{\mathrm{TM}}$ and $\langle M \rangle \in L$, then $F_L = \mathrm{RE}$.

Here $L_{\mathrm{TM}}$ denotes the language of all Turing machine encodings and $F_L$ denotes the set of functions computed by machines in $L$.

Is this true?

Comment: close, think/ agree there must be some real thm close to this like, any "nontrivial" or "sufficiently complex" language that can express its own _simulator_ is TM complete. a compiler is generally nec part of a simulator. it is indeed a "design pattern" found in many TM completeness proofs but maybe hasnt been generalized/ formalized. maybe a topic for further analysis/ discussion in [chat]. suspect/ conjecture there is some other interesting thm somewhat like "every nontrivial/ sufficiently complex recursive and recursively enumerable language can be mapped/ reduced to every other one".

Comment: I created an esoteric language called InterpretMe, which can do *nothing* but express it's own interpreter, so it's certainly not Turing complete.

Comment: Can you explain the second statement? What is $\langle M \rangle$? How is this statement related to the first?

Comment: @reinierpost $\langle M \rangle$ typically denotes the number of $M$, given some (admissible) encoding. Hence, $L_{\mathrm{TM}} = \{ \langle M \rangle \mid M \text{ is a Turing machine}\}$. By $F_L$ I denote the set of functions computed by the language $L$ of Turing machines.

Comment: A better way to state the claim would be: "If there is a TM $M$ with $\langle M \rangle \in L$ and $L_M = L$, then $F_L = \mathrm{RE}$.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The informal statement is not true, as shown by the following programming language.  Any string of, say, ASCII characters is a valid program and the meaning of every program is, "Output a program that just outputs a copy of its input." Thus, every program in this language is a compiler for the language but the language is not Turing-complete.

I'm not sure if your "computability theory version" is equivalent but it is also not true. By [Kleene's second recursion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene%27s_recursion_theorem#Kleene.27s_second_recursion_theorem), for any coding of Turing machines, there is a TM that accepts its own coding and rejects all others.<sup>1</sup> This machine is a counterexample to the proposition.
More concretely, we can achieve the result by choosing a coding. For example, let every odd number code the machine $M$ defined by "If my input is odd, accept it; otherwise, reject" and let the number $2x$ code the machine coded by $x$ in your own favourite coding scheme for Turing machines. $\langle M\rangle$ is in the language $L$ accepted by $M$ but $F_L$ is not Turing complete.

---

<sup>1</sup> Kleene's second recursion theorem says that, for any enumeration $(\phi_i)_{i\geq 0}$ of the partial recursive functions (i.e., for any coding of programs as integers), and any partial recursive function $Q(x,y)$, there is an integer $p$ such that $\phi_p$ is the function that maps $y$ to $Q(p,y)$. So, in particular, let $Q$ be the function that accepts if $x=y$ and rejects otherwise. By the theorem, there is an integer $p$ that codes the program $\phi_p(y) = Q(p,y)$. That is, $\phi_p$ accepts its own coding $p$ and rejects all other inputs.

Comment: In what sense is every program in that language a compiler for that language? Every program is a program that inputs a program in that language and outputs a different program in that language, yes, but quines are generally not considered to be compilers.

Comment: I think @immibis has a point: your compiler $c$ is $c(P) = \{ x \Rightarrow \mathtt{return}\ P \}$ whereas all programs in the language are $P(x) = P$, so $c$ is clearly not in the language. Am I missing something?

Comment: @immibis I (belatedly) think you're right. It seems that what I meant to write was that the semantics of every program is just "output your input". That seems close enough to what I wrote that it was probably what I meant to say in the first place. Or maybe I was super-lucky that the edit-distance from my wrong answer to the correct answer was so small. :-)

Comment: The answer now says "ignores its input and outputs a copy of its input" - you can't do both.

Comment: @immibis [I'll come in again](https://youtu.be/Nf_Y4MbUCLY?t=1m2s).

Comment: The identity function compiles a language to itself -- true, but that's not a very interesting compiler! Which begs the question what the author of the statement I quote meant by "implement X in X", exactly. Presumably, we are to fix a standard numbering and want to make a statement about program languages that include a program that compiles programs into indices in the standard numbering. Fix-point theorems imply immediatley that all admissible numbers have such compilers -- but is it an if and only if?

Comment: This answer would greatly benefit from stating what a compiler is assumed to be. For me, a compiler for a language is a program that takes an arbitrary program in the language and produces a program that implements the meaning of the input program.

Comment: @reinierpost And since we usually express the meaning of a program using another program, where does that leave us?

Comment: @Raphael: If you accept this answer, then every program in this language is a compiler for every other programming language.